# Using a custom html tag in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to integrate CKEditor into an internal PHP application, where in the past I was just pasting my HTML into a textarea field in a form.

This HTML that I am submitting in the form is for a custom template system that uses custom tags. These custom tags would then be replaced with real data by my backend. For example, an invoice would have the custom tag <%INVOICE#%>, which my backend would replace with the correct invoice number.

When using CKEditor, these types of tags are being converted into htmlentities such as `&lt;%INVOICE#&gt;`, which breaks my string replacement on the backend.

Is there a way to make CKEditor recognize tags that are in the format <%*%> and not convert them in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to protect those tags against modifications would be to use [config.protectedSource](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-protectedSource). With [Show Protected](http://ckeditor.com/addon/showprotected) plugin (3rd party addon), you could even see the protected code in wysiwyg area.

A more user friendly solution would be to adopt the widget-based [Placeholder](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/placeholder.html) plugin to recognize the syntax you use for custom tags. This plugin is just a proof of concept solution, so you can improve it in any way you like. E.g. by offering a select element to the end user with the list of valid placeholders instead of asking to type them manually.

Widgets are powerful, which means that it is technically possible to write even a plugin that returns `<%INVOICE#%>` in source code, but shows the real invoice number in wysiwyg area.